# find error log for streaming replication

Tags: postgresql, replication, master-slave-replication, postgresql-12

Recently the streaming replication fails after I restart the primary. I can not find the record using `select * from pg_stat_replication`

Now, I want to see it from the system log file at `/var/log/postgresql#` on the primary.
I find the following using `grep -i -m 10 **fatal** postgresql-12-main.log`:

```
2022-12-06 01:56:01.890 UTC [11513] FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
2022-12-05 11:36:57.024 UTC [27076] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 27089) exited with exit code 1
2022-12-05 11:36:57.637 UTC [2465] rep_user@[unknown] LOG:  standby "12/main" is now a synchronous standby with priority 1
2022-12-06 01:55:27.344 UTC [11360] FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

I have tried some keywords that might be able to be `grep`-ed like : replication, slave, ip address of the client and physical. But I do not find anything.

BTW, I do not turn on the postgres log file so there is no file at `var/lib/postgresql/12/main/log`.

There is no error on the replica side. I have `grep` keyword like fatal and error. Nothing.

What are the keywords that I can `grep` to find errors related to replication?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are too many connections open on the primary server. You have to close some if you want the standby to be able to connect.

Comment: okay. I read this on how to close connection : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058649/psql-fatal-too-many-connections-for-role. It said "...you don't want to terminate important queries (or connections) that way.". If **I have to** restart the postgre service, then all the connections in `pg_stat_activity` will be wiped out. So how can one terminate something important? Just wait till they finish and then restart? @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: If you terminate a connection, be it with a restart of the database server or with `pg_terminate_backend`, you are going to hurt some client whose connection gets interrupted. That cannot be avoided. You can use a "smart shutdown" that does not terminate existing connections, but then new connections will be denied service.

Comment: Ok. Furthermore, how can the "too many connections" error happens when I have `max_connections` 700 and `count pg_stat_activity` only 193 records? It just does not adds up. Another fact, I see so many errors related to `queries` such as `no relation found`. The log file itself is huge : 92MB (yesterday) and 1GB(2 days ago). @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: The database server can count to 700. But there could also be a separate, more restrictive limit set on the database or the database user. The errors you see are not directly related and caused by your program doing weird things.